# UIAlertView in iOS7 locks up display on dismiss

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7

I had no problem with the following code in iOS versions before iOS7 came out, and now when I try to run this on iOS7 I get undesired results.

```
[self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
mAlert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"There are no more reports matching this search query." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[mAlert show];
[SVProgressHUD dismiss];
```

The alert message will come up and prompt the user to hit OK. When the alert dismisses, I am left with a view now that can no longer be interacted with, and the only solution is to re-run the app. The app itself isn't "frozen" as in I profile it and can see it is still alive, I just can't interact with it. I implement the UIAlertViewDelegate and below is my implementation of the didDismissWithButtonIndex: function

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:  (NSInteger)buttonIndex {
mAlert = nil;
}
```

I've tried several things, and still nothing. Incredibly frustrating and I feel like I am missing something trivial.

Comment: Is your code that creates and displays the alert running on the main thread?  Is some other block of code setting `setUserInteractionEnabled:NO` and happens to be running at the same time?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to clarify. If I comment out the one line "[mAlert show];" the application continues to run fine. If I show the alert, the alert comes up and I can dismiss it no problem. But once it is dismissed, I can no longer interact with the UI.

Comment: Are you showing the alert in background thread?

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure the method is running in the main thread? Any method that does something with the UI needs to run on the main thread, and not a background thread.

If you want to show the alert from a background thread, try this in your background method:

```
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showAlert) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

And add a method like this

```
- (void) showAlert {
    UIAlertView *mAlert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"There are no more reports matching this search query." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [mAlert show];
}
```